# What is the Scanner class used for in Java?

Tags: java

In Java, what is the Scanner class used for?

Comment: David - the Java platform documentation (Javadocs) is excellent.  It should be the first place you look when you want to learn how to use framework classes.  http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A simple text scanner which can parse
>   primitive types and strings using
>   regular expressions.

Basically, you can initialize a Scanner with some input stream and a format or delimiter, then use it to iterate over "tokens" (broken-up chunks of text) that it generates from that input stream with the delimiter info you give it.

Answer (score 2):

> Objects of type Scanner are useful for
>   breaking down formatted input into
>   tokens and translating individual
>   tokens according to their data type.

from sun [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html)