# Issue on string comparison

Tags: java

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class compute_volume
{
   public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
       InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);
       boolean answer;
       double radius,height;
       final double pi = 3.14159;
       do{System.out.println("Enter the radius,press enter and then enter the height");
       String t = input.readLine();
       radius = Integer.parseInt(t);
       t = input.readLine();
       height = Integer.parseInt(t);
       System.out.println("The volume of a cylinder with radius " + radius + " and height " + height + " is " + (pi*pi*height) + "\n Thanks for using my cylinder volume calculator.Enter \"yes\" to use again or \"no\" to stop.");
       t = input.readLine();
       System.out.println(t);
       if ( t == "yes"){
           answer = true;
        }else{ 
            answer= false;
        }
    }while(answer);
    }
}
```

**Problem**:

The user inputs `yes` but the calculator doesn't restart.

**Solution**:

That's what I don't know ,and hope to know by posting this here.

Comment: This question deserves an upvote?  C'mon guys...

Comment: What? I propose that each and every Java book author places this on the cover. With red underscored caps.

Answer (score 6):

use

```
if ( "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(t))
```

instead of

```
  if ( t == "yes")
```

equals method checks the content of strings while == checks for object equality.

Read related post for your understanding :

[Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: +1...I have been facing the same problem with string comparison some days ago. I did `String.contentEquals("")` to solve it. At first I had thought thought that the `==` operator would work as it does in C#. Good to know the answer I found was correct. :)

Answer (score 6):

Incorrect `String` comparison, instead of:

```
if ( t == "yes"){
```

you should have

```
if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(t)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals()` instead of `==` to compare `String`s.

```
"yes".equals(t)
```

[Read this thread for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

In Java, for String, remember to use "equals()" but not "==".

```
answer="yes".equalsIgnoreCase(t);
```

replace the code:

```
    if ( t == "yes"){
       answer = true;
    }else{ 
        answer= false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct this:

```
if ( "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(t))
```

rather then

```
  if ( t == "yes")
```

If we not override Equals() then by default Equals() of Object class is called.So it will compare contents rather than object.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use as follows

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class compute_volume {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean answer;
    double radius,height;
    final double pi = 3.14159;
    do{System.out.println("Enter the radius,press enter and then enter the height");
        String t = sc.nextLine();
        radius = Double.parseDouble(t);
        t = sc.nextLine();
        height = Double.parseDouble(t);
        System.out.println("The volume of a cylinder with radius " + radius + " and height " + height + " is " + (pi*pi*height) + "\n Thanks for using my cylinder volume calculator.Enter \"yes\" to use again or \"no\" to stop.");
        t = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(t);
        if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
            answer = true;
        }else{
            answer= false;
        }
    }while(answer);
}
}
```

Comment: import java.util.Scanner

Comment: Still what is it actually?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406122/what-is-the-scanner-class-used-for-in-java